# how can I center an embedded youtube video

Tags: html, css, video

so I am making a webpage for videos on ghack the name of gaming community

and so far so good im just running into one issue. I cannot center the youtube video i have embedded (its just a  random test video I have yet to make the real one)

i want the video to be right under the text I have that says "welcome to the new generation". bit its off to the left too much. how can i center it more

this is my CSS with some taken out that I have not used or that are not relevant

```
body{
        background-color:black;
    }



    .logo{
        width: 50%;
        border-width: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: red;
    }


    .h1{
        size:50px;
        color: red;
        text-align: center;

    }

    .divYT{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 50%;


    }
```

and this is my HTML

```
    <<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    GHack
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystylee.css"> 
</head>
<body>

<div class="logo">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/qoJbVdY.png" alt="G-HACK" height="150">
</div>

<div class="divA">
    <h1 class="h1">Welcome To the new genaration  </h1>
<div>
<!-- replace video with youtube video that shows off the  in the div under this comment  -->

</div class="divYT">
    <iframe align=center width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GEWkjYssiCw" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

this is a picture of my webpage that I have drawn on to show where I want the video to be http://prntscr.com/icsjux

the green box is where I want the video, and the blue box is where the video is

Comment: You should to change : `</div class="divYT">` to `<div class="divYT">`

Comment: that is no issue as that was some how added in the reformation to fix on here. in my code it doesn't have the / in that spot

Comment: It is very much an issue and, no, there is no edit history of anyone adding anything to your "code".

Comment: omg you guys get ZERO of what im saying. im saying when i had to REFORMAT the code to have it show in the CODE TAG on this WEBSITE that SLASH must of some how got in that spot. because in my CODE that SLASH is NOT in that SPOT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a fixed width for the iFrame, you can give the wrapping `<div>` element (`<div class="divYT">`) the following CSS rules:

```
.divYT {
  width: 560px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

That will make the wrapping element to have the same width as the video, and make equal margins from both left and right, which will result in centering that wrapping element.